# How to escape when cornered by enemies?

Tags: dark-souls

It unfortunately seems more than plausible to get surrounded by enemies against some obstacle — I haven't yet rang the first bell and I've been "corner-locked" at least four times, for instance:

- on the lower area of the Undead Parish church, with the undead knights, against corners
- on the graveyard, with the skeletons, against gravestone formations

This is not a "stunlock" since my character is not in a permanent stunned state, but only can't move (essentially) anywhere due to enemy model collision. Stamina runs out near-immediately when attempting to block several foes at once and I'm uncertain if there are many spells or items with a low enough wind-up time in the entire game. Rolling doesn't appear to affect the collision detection and I suppose that it isn't possible to "jump" immediately (requires running,f if that would even help in any way).

In essence, the enemies occasionally happen to block the player who as a result may not have any real change to finish any attacks.

Answer (score 3):

In these particular situations, you've got a lot of fast moving enemies piling up on you all at once. This is by design, and unless managed properly, will end up in the situation you find yourself in. So the issue is not *escape* so much as avoidance of *creating* the situation to begin with. The way you can achieve this is:

1. "Pulling": this is basically done by grabbing the attention of one enemy, either from a distance (i.e. with a bow) to come to you so you can deal with them in a safer area, with less enemies, or by slowly walking into their aggro range (with the skeletons for example) then retreating.
2. Funneling: similar to pulling, but if you have too many enemies on you, find an area you can move to that basically forces the enemies into a single file, such as a stairwell or a corridor.

If, for some reason you still do manage to find yourself surrounded however, stamina management is the key. You want to roll/block to avoid as much damage as possible, and look for an opening to attack. Attacking will provide a small amount of knockback, and potentially allow for an opening to appear. It may require 2 or more hits, but you should be able to push through fairly easily.

AOE attacks also help - the [Force miracle](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Force) would be ideal, but firebombs would also work well.

Ultimately though, death is not the end; so long as you pay attention to what's going on, even if you do die, you can come back, knowing that you need to be careful in this area, and approach it more cautiously to retrieve your lost souls and humanity.